# Solving $x$ for $y= 3^x-2^x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a way to solve for $x$ given the function: $$y= 3^x-2^x$$ in terms of $y$?

I tried a lot of algebraic manipulations but I ended up nothing. Or, should we say it it impossible to do so?

Comment: It's $\rm\ Z^C - Z\: =\: Y\ $ for $\rm\ Z = 2^X,\:\ C = log_2 3$.

Comment: $x,y$ are what?  Natural numbers?

Comment: any positive real numbers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no expression for $x$ in closed form as an elementary function of $y$.

Comment: How come? is there a proof why it has no closed form? If not elementary, is there a closed form? thanks

Comment: These proofs aren't easy, and I certainly can't come up with one myself. Do a search for terms like "closed form" and "elementary function" and you may see what you are up against.

Comment: thanks. But, is there a form extending from elementary functions?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I could be wrong - not every function is my personal friend.